# Get-NetIPAddress returns values not found in ipconfig

Tags: powershell, ipconfig, windows-networking

We are doing a configuration inventory of servers in our system, and found something odd.  Two of our servers share this anomaly:
When we run PowerShell Get-NetIPAddress as follows:

```
Get-NetIPAddress -addressstate Preferred -addressfamily ipv4
```

Three IP addresses are returned.  They are 192.x.x.x, 127.0.0.1, and 169.x.x.x.  The 169 address, in both cases, reportedly are on Interface Alias **Local Area Connectiuon* 11**  The IP addresses are different from one another, but both in the 169.254.0.0/16 network (16-bit mask).

However, "ipconfig /all" for these two servers does not show the 169 address at all.

Control Panel / Network and Internet / Network Connections also does not show anythong other than the interface for 192.168.x.x.

Where might I look to determine where Get-NetIPAddress is getting this information?

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-NetIPAddress -addressstate Preferred -addressfamily ipv4


IPAddress         : 192.168.10.xxx
InterfaceIndex    : 13
InterfaceAlias    : Ethernet 2
AddressFamily     : IPv4
Type              : Unicast
PrefixLength      : 24
PrefixOrigin      : Manual
SuffixOrigin      : Manual
AddressState      : Preferred
ValidLifetime     : Infinite ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue)
PreferredLifetime : Infinite ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue)
SkipAsSource      : False
PolicyStore       : ActiveStore

**IPAddress         : 169.254.xxx.xxx
InterfaceIndex    : 14
InterfaceAlias    : Local Area Connection* 11
AddressFamily     : IPv4
Type              : Unicast
PrefixLength      : 16
PrefixOrigin      : WellKnown
SuffixOrigin      : Link
AddressState      : Preferred
ValidLifetime     : Infinite ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue)
PreferredLifetime : Infinite ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue)
SkipAsSource      : False
PolicyStore       : ActiveStore**

IPAddress         : 127.0.0.1
InterfaceIndex    : 1
InterfaceAlias    : Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
AddressFamily     : IPv4
Type              : Unicast
PrefixLength      : 8
PrefixOrigin      : WellKnown
SuffixOrigin      : WellKnown
AddressState      : Preferred
ValidLifetime     : Infinite ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue)
PreferredLifetime : Infinite ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue)
SkipAsSource      : False
PolicyStore       : ActiveStore

PS C:\Windows\system32> 
PS C:\Windows\system32> ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : GotDomVM1
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : gotnet.net
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : gotnet.net

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Failover Cluster Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 02-87-4F-xx-xx-xx
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-xx-xx-xx
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b074:d74d:6320:dab0%13(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.xxx(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.xxx
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 251663709
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-25-F9-6D-6F-00-15-xx-xx-xx-xx
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : ::1
                                       192.168.10.x
                                       192.168.10.y
                                       127.0.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{6D49450E-C01F-4FF3-9CF8-033D67921AA6}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-xx-xx-xx-xx
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{2B8A29E1-13B1-4311-A1F7-6CDBA190EC28}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Thanks,
Dennis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as to why it has a 169 address at all:

[What is a Microsoft Failover Cluster Virtual Adapter anyway?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/askcore/what-is-a-microsoft-failover-cluster-virtual-adapter-anyway)

> Like other adapters, the Microsoft Failover Cluster Virtual Adapter
> has a MAC address and both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses assigned to it. The
> IPv4 address is an Automatic Private Internet Protocol Addressing
> (APIPA) address

But why it doesn't show up using `ipconfig /all`? Probably because it's disconnected. It still has an IP address assigned, so `Get-NetIPAddress` sees that, but ipconfig doesn't really care about inactive IPs. the linked MS blog specifically shows it working normally with ipconfig:

> it is plainly visible when listing the network configuration of a Cluster node using the ipconfig /all command line.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer; makes perfect sense.  I will ask the client about the clustering.  Last position was that there was no clustering in the installation.  Perhaps it was configured but not used.  At any rate, thanks!  You've solved my mystery.